# How to Copy a Single Vertex Group to a Selected Object?

Tags: vertex-groups

The **Copy Vertex Group to Selected** operator replaces my other vertex groups instead of just copying it over. How can I just add a copied group as a new (another) group without replacing existing one?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use **Data Transfer** modifier.

Here you have two objects (*Cube_A, Cube_B*). *Cube_A* with assigned vertex group **Group_A**

[image]

*Cube_B* has already assigned vertex group **Group_B**. To bring vertex group of *Cube_A* add a new vertex group channel (here named **Group_C**) as a storage for transferred data.

[image]

Now with Cube_B still selected add **Transfer Data** modifier with setup...

- *Source* **Cube_A**
- keep *Mix Mode* **Replace**
- enable *Vertex Data* > **Vertex Group**
- *Mapping* > **Topology**
- *Layer Selection* > **Group_A**, *Layer Mapping* > **Group_C**

[image]

... you can see effect via Vertex Group Weights (enabled under Overlay options).

[image]

If you need to make the *Vertex Group* real enable in modifier under *Topology Mapping* > **Max Distance** and than **Apply** modifier.

[image]

Note: If you can't use *Topology* you can use **Nearest Vertex**, but for success disable *Global space* icon next to *Source* field and set *Max Distance* to something very low (just not default zero).

---

*Undernote: Yes, the operator "Copy Vertex Group to Selection" is misleading for me too ... *Replace Vertex Groups by Active* sounds me more correct for current action.*

Comment: Apart from that the DataTransfer looks a bit different in my current Blender version - how do I get the vertex groups from the source object onto the object with the modifier? In the current version of the modifier you have a Mix Mode which can be set to Replace, Add, Subtract, Mix etc., but if I add the vertex groups from the source object, the groups appear in the target object - but each group simply contains all vertices, not the selections of the source object. I guess I'm doing it wrong? Maybe you could give a more elaborate answer on how to use this DataTransfer modifier?

Comment: I've seen that it's an older version, but I still don't know what to do. When I apply the modifier and try to select the vertices from Group_C, it simply selects all vertices - not those which are correspondent to those in Group_A of the other object, although both objects have the same geometry.

Comment: I am having the same issue as well. it simply transfers with the entire mesh selected

Comment: Another thing is: if I have 10 vertex groups on one object that I want to transfer, do I have to repeat this process (assumed it works as expected) 10 times for each group?

Comment: @vklidu Well, I was asking for the 10 groups in the context of the original question... "if you don't have any other to keep", then this whole thread would not exist ;)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann ... for OP - sure, for you - I couldn't know ... :) With 10 vertex groups - yes, one by one, I would say. I updated my A, seems to be working now and I deleted my previous comments to clear it here a bit from not relevant ones.

Comment: I'm just talking about the topic here theoretical - I don't need it actually. But in the question he says, it "replaces my other vertex groups", so at least one of the objects has more than one group. I personally would do it manually if I only wanted to copy a single group if all else fails. Or if I didn't need the vertex selection, only a couple of groups, I'd simply add new ones to the object. What I thought this could do and might be helpful from time to time, if you created several groups on some object to have vertex selections of special areas, that you can transfer these as well.

Comment: You see, since vertex weights were not mentioned in the question, I was thinking of other things you can do with the groups. Like selecting / deselecting certain vertices/faces of the mesh for assigning materials, or hiding them in _Edit Mode_ etc. And I was wondering if you have to do it one by one since there are options like "All Layers" and mapping like "By Name" or "By Order".